# How do I get the original value of an attribute of a model using the gem PaperTrail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, paper-trail-gem

I have a model that is tracked using PaperTrail.

I would like to compare the current value of the attribute 'name' to the value when it was first created. I can get the current value easily. How do I get its original value?

To get its current value: `widget.name`

To get its original value: `widget.versions.first.???.name`

I know that `widget.versions.first.changeset` will return a hash as follows.

```rb
{
    name: [nil, 'original name']
}
```

Although, I do not want to parse it; there must be a better way to obtain the original value.

Comment: Without `reify`, you're kind of stuck parsing.  However, if you're only looking for the original name, you may be able to accomplish what you want syntactically using metadata, see https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata ... Essentially create an `original_name` metadata attribute and store on create.  Then you'll have it available as a first-class function on the version object: `widget.versions.first.original_name`. But if you're after more than just the name, this will be more tedious than just parsing, I'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code ended up resolving the issue.

`original = widget.versions.where(event: 'create')[0].changeset['name'][1]`

It's ugly but it works! I can "monkey patch" it into PaperTrail to clean it up.

Comment: Hrmm...for me "changeset" always returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `reify` on the second `version` or return the `widget` if not present.

There's a [closed issue](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/475) about `reify` returning `nil` on the Github repo. It got ignored over there but I think this is a very valid issue and a common use-case.

Doing `widget.versions.first.reify` returns `nil` so the best way I could find is this:

```
widget.versions.second.reify
```

But that doesn't work when the object doesn't have any changes. So you need a `nil` check in there:

```
widget.versions.second&.reify || widget
```

This looks for the second version and if it's present will call `reify`, which returns the original object. If it's not present it will simply return the `widget` itself.

If you want to be clean about it, you can add this as a method to the class:

```
# Returns the original version of this object or just this object if there has been no changes.
def original_version
  self.versions.second&.reify || self
end
```

I have an open Issue/Feature Request with PaperTrail to add `original_version` to the core library itself:

https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/1204

Give it an upvote if you want it in there.

Answer (score 0):

something that you can also do (a bit hacky and could not work on all use cases) is:

```rb
class MyModel
  has_paper_trail on: [:touch]
  after_save { touch }
end
```

That way:

- you have the create version in your versions
- you have the live version in your versions
- BUT you cannot leverage the version#event anymore (it will always be "touch")